# Is it okay to delete a POSIX timer in the event handler function?

Tags: c, linux

### The Question

If I call `create_timer` with the `SIGEV_THREAD` constant stored in the `sigev_notify` field in my `sigevent` structure, then when the timer event happens, my `sigev_notify_function` callback will be called.

Are there any hidden implications or undesirable side-effects to calling `timer_delete` *from within my callback function*?

**Specific Concerns**

My initial thought was that it should be fine. However, I don't fully understand the mechanics that are operating behind the scenes, and I'm concerned about there being proper cleanup of the callback's thread and handling of the signals if the timer and it's associated structures are removed before handling is complete.

### Background

Another SO user asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29799925/2615940), which essentially says, "do I really need to delete my timers after calling `timer_create`? My answer was a resounding **yes**. He then asked a follow-up question in the comments: "is it okay to do that from the timer callback function?" and I didn't have a good answer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that in principle it is not allowed to call `timer_create` or `timer_delete`, at least on Linux. [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) is only allowing *async-signal-safe* functions to be called directly or indirectly from a signal handler, and strangely `timer_create` and `timer_delete` is not listed amongst them (perhaps it is a typo and they both should be listed as async-signal-safe, since both [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) & [timer_delete(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_delete.2.html) are in section 2 of the man pages, and appear in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html))

Notice that POSIX [signal concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04) page does not list `timer_create` as possible in a signal handler. I imagine that on some operating systems these timer functions might be implemented entirely in the C library (not in the kernel).

My guess (since `timer_create` and `timer_delete` is a [*syscall*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) **on Linux** listed in `<asm/unistd.h>`)  is that *`timer_create` and `timer_delete`* are in fact async-signal-safe so *can be called from a **Linux** signal handler*. This might be false on other POSIX implementations.

Comment: It sounds like a resounding *maybe*. I think it would be best to just avoid doing it. The main thread has to keep running anyway, since the callback is a new thread in the same process, so it would probably be safer to delete the timer from the main thread right before exiting. Good explanations though! You referred to some resources that I didn't think to look at.

Comment: The OP specifically asks about using `create_timer` with `SIGEV_THREAD`, which has different behavior (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40491337/5689220)).

Answer (score 2):

According to [`sigevent(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sigevent.7.html), when you use `SIGEV_THREAD`, the callback is executed in the following way:

> Notify the process by invoking `sigev_notify_function` "as if" it were
>   the start function of a new thread.  (Among the implementation
>   possibilities here are that each timer notification could result in
>   the creation of a new thread, or that a single thread is created to
>   receive all notifications.)

So as far as you (the programmer) know, your notify function is being executed in the context of a new thread, *not* in the context of a standard signal handler routine that interrupts another thread's execution. Thus the rules for async-signal-safe functions do not apply, contrary to what was mentioned in Basile's answer, and so you can do anything your heart desires in your notify function when using `SIGEV_THREAD` with your timers. This includes calling `timer_delete` to delete the `timer_t`.